# Llega la notificacion de merchant_order pero no la de payment en el sandbox para checkout basico

Tags: mercadopago, yii2, pago-in-app

Estoy recibiendo mal las notificaciones o es un error del sandbox?

Una vez que realizo una operacion en el sandbox la veo como "pagada" y me llegan las siguientes notificaciones

"POST /mercadopago/ipn?topic=merchant_order&id=467321793 HTTP/1.1" 404 8277 "-" "MercadoPago Feed v2.0 merchant_order"

en esta veo la informacion de la compra, pero sin la informacion del pago, y luego me llega la siguiente que por lo que entiendo intenta notificar el pago pero no es el formato que especifica el sdk, y el id tampoco lo encuentra

"POST /mercadopago/ipn?type=payment&data.id=3094736 HTTP/1.1" 404 8277 "-" "MercadoPago WebHook v1.0 payment"

Alguna idea?

Desde ya muchas gracias

---

Si agrego el parametro notification url, no importa que el checkout sea basico en el sandbox igual me notifica con un Webhook lo cual entiendo esta mal, porque eso sucede cuando el checkout es custom, saque ese parametro pero sigo sin recibir la notificacion de tipo payment

*Parametro eliminado*

"notification_url": "https://www.your-site.com/ipn"

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo. Pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: pudiste resolverlo de alguna forma? porque estoy con el mismo problema. Gracias!

Comment: La solución a esto fue no usar el Sandbox, ya que es una basofia, y usar el ambiente de produccion de mercadopago con las credenciales y tarjetas de test que es posible crear desde la pagina de developers (la verdad completamente decepcionado con esto).-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a esto fue no usar el Sandbox, y usar el ambiente de producción de MercadoPago con las credenciales y tarjetas de test que es posible crear desde la página de Developers.

Answer (score 1):

MercadoPago manda dos notificaciones, una tipo POST y una tipo GET.

Siempre debes configurar el `notification_url` y con la función que crees para recibir esta vas a procesar el pago en tu base de datos (de esta puedes sacar el `external_id`, etc) y también debes tener configurado las `back_urls`, que estas son para notificarle al cliente/usuario el estado del pago (`success`, `failed`, `pending`).